# IORING_ENTER_SQ_WAKEUP - undefined reference to `io_uring_enter'

Tags: c, linux, io-uring

I'm trying to run some tests using IORING_SETUP_SQPOLL, but when it's set and I call `io_uring_cqe_get_data(cqe);` I get "cqe failed: Bad file descriptor". Reading about Kernel Side Polling in [io_uring.pdf](https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf), it seems that I might have to call:

```
/* fills in new sqe entries */
    add_more_io(); 
 
/*
 * need to call io_uring_enter() to make the kernel notice the new IO
 * if polled and the thread is now sleeping.
 */
if ((*sqring→flags) & IORING_SQ_NEED_WAKEUP)
    io_uring_enter(ring_fd, to_submit, to_wait, IORING_ENTER_SQ_WAKEUP);
```

but when I try to compile it, gcc cannot find io_uring_enter() (undefined reference to `io_uring_enter')

- I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS - kernel: 5.4.0-62-generic.
- [The code can be found here](https://gist.github.com/albertopires/2e368051e7a58c9e551777c21de2f835)

Does anyone have some experience with this option/flag?

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. Seems you may be missing an include file in your source.

Comment: A quick google search turned up https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/an-introduction-to-the-io_uring-asynchronous-io-framework. Did you include `liburing.h`?

Comment: @jwdonahue, yes I did, and also liburing/io_uring.h. It seems that there is no definition in the source code as well. I've included a link to the source code in the question.

Comment: Late answer, but for anyone getting the gcc error you have to add liburing as a library: `gcc main.c -luring`